# <apex:inputfield> is not allowing me to enter more than 20 characters

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

is not allowing me to enter more than 20 characters is there any limit?  And when I created  it is not showing red color mark in visual force page..I didn't get what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The fields that are you using as values in "apex:inputfield" have text limit 20 character.
That's way this will happen.

For example

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
<apex:form>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Account.TestField__c}" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If my TestField__c is type of "Text(10)" then its allowed to enter only 10 char in above page.